# Запись с экрана в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

При подключении реального устройства для отладки(HUAWEI U9500) в Android Studio не могу записать видео с экрана телефона. Кнопка "Screen Record" остаётся не активной. Кнопка "Screen Capture" работает нормально. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Работает только для Android 4.4 и выше - http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord